# extract the value between a tag and add title attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, siebel, extract-value

I have several a tags as shown below on a dynamically generated page

```
<a href='JavaScript:SWETargetGotoURL(vtUrl+"XRX+eCustomer+Account+Inventory+View", "_self")'  id='s_ViewBar' name=s_ViewBar>&nbsp;Inventory&nbsp;</a>
```

I need to traverse through all the **a** tags containing the text **"SWETargetGotoURL"** in their href tag and depending on the text I need to add the title tag

for example

```
if(extractedtext == "&nbsp;Inventory&nbsp;")
   title = "This is inventory homepage";
```

The a tag should finally look like this

```
<a href='JavaScript:SWETargetGotoURL(vtUrl+"XRX+eCustomer+Account+Inventory+View", "_self")'  title = "This is inventory homepage" id='s_ViewBar' name=s_ViewBar>&nbsp;Inventory&nbsp;</a>
```

I used following code to get all the tags with specific value in href tag but I am unable to get the text in between and I don't know how to run a loop and work on all the a tags

```
 var screenName = $('a[href*="SWETargetGotoURL"]').attr('href');
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) which iterates over the set of selected elements.

```
$('a[href*="SWETargetGotoURL"]').each(function () {

    //get the text of the element
    var extractedtext = $(this).text();

    //check text for match
    if (extractedtext == "&nbsp;Inventory&nbsp;") {

        //Change title attribute of element
        $(this).attr('title', "This is inventory homepage");
    }
});
```